# Links within Bootbox modal are not clickable

Tags: javascript, facebook, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to load a Facebook login button in a Twitter bootstrap modal dialog:

```
$("a.fb-login, .modal a.fb-login").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    FB.login(function(response) {
    // ...
```

This works fine for buttons placed outside of the modal dialog, but when the element is rendered within a dialog (triggered from bootbox), clicking the link just makes the dialog disappear, not launch the Facebook popup in a new window:

```
// when 401 unauthorized
message = $("#login-form").clone();
bootbox.modal(message)
```

Comment: Is the callback getting called when the button is clicked from within the modal?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the listener is only getting attached to the elements currently on the page when you call the `on()` method.

If you want to be able to handle events on newly created elements without having to reattach the listener, try attaching the listener to the entire page, but use a selector to filter out the events like so:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.fb-login, .modal a.fb-login', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  FB.login(function(response) {
  // ...
```

Obviously, narrowing down where you attach the listener is good practice.